# Apex Date Parse Invalid Date in IE11 - Valid In Chrome

Tags: apex, date, chrome, internet-explorer

I have a string `searchStartDate` coming from an input field on a VF page.

The input is `03/20/2019`

Once passed to the apex controller I debug the string before parsing it.

In IE11:

> 08:02:13:041 USER_DEBUG [1386]|DEBUG|searchStartDate: ‎3‎/‎20‎/‎2019

In Chrome:

> 08:01:04:058 USER_DEBUG [1386]|DEBUG|searchStartDate: 3/20/2019

When performing `Date searchStartDateDate = Date.parse(searchStartDate);` IE 11 returns the following error, while Chrome successfully parses the date.

> Invalid date: ‎3‎/‎20‎/‎2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 11 doesn't have great `date` support. Heres a stackoverflow question about pretty much the same thing:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943879/date-parse-failing-in-ie-11-with-nan

> According to MDN docs for Date.parse() parameter:
>
> > dateString
> >
> > A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).
>
> Looks like Microsoft simply didn't implement the format you provided. I wouldn't use this format anyway, because it's locale dependent(might just be dd/mm/yyyy or sometimes might also fit mm/dd/yyyy).
>
> An alternative to your solution is to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Basiclly since IE 11 won't do it out of the box you'll need either some custom code (try looking up polyfills for IE) or a date library.

---

These are far from the only issues with IE 11 & dates. See this [blog post](https://www.csgpro.com/blog/2016/08/a-bad-date-with-internet-explorer-11-trouble-with-new-unicode-characters-in-javascript-date-strings) for some other issues.

The ideal solution would be to not use IE 11, but thats not always realistic.

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant, but maybe I misunderstand. This Date.parse is in Apex, not javascript, isn't this being evaluated on the server/salesforce side, not the browser side?

Comment: The strings look identical - I would expect 0 differences between the two in apex. Apex runs server side & wouldn't be effected by the browser the client uses. Try looking harder at the variable being passed - there may be some issue that isn't obvious from your post. There should be no difference in behavior on the server side when provided the same inputs.

Comment: Try an `assert(dateString, '03/01/2019');`. There may be an issue with the actual text itself being passed along. i still think your best answer is to handle this in the browser itself to ensure apex gets a valid date value.

Comment: Just a thought, but you might want to try passing not the actual date, but the total number of milliseconds that the date stores internally. Using that value instead of a formatted string might help your code work better cross-platform.

Comment: You were in the right domain. Even though the strings looked identical, there were invisible unicode strings in IE 11 due to my use of .toLocaleDateString(); 

https://www.csgpro.com/blog/2016/08/a-bad-date-with-internet-explorer-11-trouble-with-new-unicode-characters-in-javascript-date-strings

Comment: Thats why I linked that SO question - they were talking about unicode strings in the date string - they must have been passed along into the server. Glad it helped!